# Combination of elements

Tags: scala

**Problem:**

Given a `Seq` `seq` and an `Int` `n`.

I basically want all combinations of the elements **up to** size n. The arrangement **matters**, meaning e.g. [1,2] is different that [2,1].

```
def combinations[T](seq: Seq[T], size: Int) = ...
```

**Example:**

```
combinations(List(1,2,3), 0) 
//Seq(Seq())

combinations(List(1,2,3), 1)
//Seq(Seq(), Seq(1), Seq(2), Seq(3))

combinations(List(1,2,3), 2) 
//Seq(Seq(), Seq(1), Seq(2), Seq(3), Seq(1,2), Seq(2,1), Seq(1,3), Seq(3,1),
//Seq(2,3), Seq(3,2))

...
```

**What I have so far:**

```
def combinations[T](seq: Seq[T], size: Int) = {
 @tailrec
  def inner(seq: Seq[T], soFar: Seq[Seq[T]]): Seq[Seq[T]] = seq match {
    case head +: tail => inner(tail, soFar ++ {
      val insertList = Seq(head)
      for {
        comb <- soFar
        if comb.size < size
        index <- 0 to comb.size
      } yield comb.patch(index, insertList, 0)
    })
    case _ => soFar
  }

  inner(seq, IndexedSeq(IndexedSeq.empty))
}
```

What would be your approach to this problem? This method will be called **a lot** and therefore it should be made most efficient.

There are methods in the library like `subsets` or `combinations` (yea I chose the same name), which return iterators. I also thought about that, but I have no idea yet how to design this lazily.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124440/code-to-enumerate-permutations-in-scala

Comment: I'd try built-in permutations method

Comment: Inserting an element into the list at the end potentially has complexity N where N is the length of list, by the way.

Comment: @Ashalynd Thanks for the link. I somehow did not check for a permuations method. I still feel that my problem is slightly different, in the "up to size n" aspect.

Comment: You are right with the `O(n)` on appending with `List`. In my code I use it only with `IndexedSeq`, but I wanted to make it more general. Probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this is efficient enough for your purpose but it's the simplest approach.

```
def combinations[T](seq: Seq[T], size: Int) : Seq[Seq[T]] = {
  (1 to size).flatMap(i => seq.combinations(i).flatMap(_.permutations))
}
```

edit:
to make it lazy you can use a view

```
def combinations[T](seq: Seq[T], size: Int) : Iterable[Seq[T]] = {
  (1 to size).view.flatMap(i => seq.combinations(i).flatMap(_.permutations))
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is simple. It should be `(0 to size)` though, because the empty `Seq` is included.

Comment: Efficiency-wise I'm not sure, because you don't reuse results. In my solution it's the following: Assume I have all combinations for 1 and 2, like [...,[1,2],...]. Then the result is: [..., [3,1,2], [1,3,2],[1,2,3], ...]. I just insert the next element on all possible positions from existing solutions.

Answer (score 3):

From permutations theory we know that the number of permutations of K elements taken from a set of N elements is

```
N! / (N - K)!
```

(see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation)

Therefore if you wanna build them all, you will have

```
algorithm complexity = number of permutations * cost of building each permutation
```

The potential optimization of the algorithm lies in minimizing the cost of building each permutation, by using a data structure that has some `appending` / `prepending` operation that runs in `O(1)`.

You are using an `IndexedSeq`, which is a collection optimized for O(1) random access. When collections are optimized for random access they are backed by arrays. When using such collections (this is also valid for java `ArrayList`) you give up the guarantee of a low cost insertion operation: sometimes the array won't be big enough and the collection will have to create a new one and copy all the elements.

When using instead `linked lists` (such as scala `List`, which is the default implementation for Seq) you take the opposite choice: you give up constant time access for constant time insertion. In particular, scala `List` is a recursive data structure with constant time insertion at the front.

So if you are looking for high performance and you need the collection to be available eagerly, use a `Seq.empty` instead of `IndexedSeq.empty` and at each iteration prepend the new element at the head of the `Seq`. If you need something lazy, use `Stream` which will minimize memory occupation. Additional strategies worth exploring is to create an empty IndexedSeq for your first iteration, but not through Indexed.empty. Use instead the builder and try to provide an array which has the right size `(N! / (N-K)!)`

Comment: Thank you for your post. It is true that I can use the fact that I know the size of the output collection. Though it is `N! / (N - 0)! + N! / (N - 1)! + ... + N! / (N - size)!`, as you can see from my examples I want it "up to the size". I'll give it a shot.