# Scala possible combinations of collection of integers

Tags: algorithm, scala

I have written following code to return all possible combinations of Array of Integers

```
def  findAllCombinations ( remain:Array[Int], partial:Array[Int],cum :List[Array[Int]]) : List[Array[Int]]=  {
  for ( i <- 0 until remain.size) {
    val m = partial ++ Array(remain(i))
    val n = m::cum
    findAllCombinations(remain.slice(i+1 ,remain.size),m,n)
  }
  cum
}
```

When I call this function using following parameters I am getting empty list.

```
findAllCombinations(Array(1,2,3),Array(),List(Array()))
```

Can somebody help me in improving the code?

Comment: Values are immutable, you are discarding all generated values, `foteach` returns unit. And you shouldn't be exposing intermediate values like `partial` to the caller. - In case, if you do not understand why this code is returning an empty list, you should start with a simpler exercise first

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8124741/2359227

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the `for` causes invocations of `findAllCombinations` but then it returns the `cum` that the base invocation was called with, which is `List(Array())`.

- `0 until remain.size` evaluates to a `scala.collection.immutable.Range`
- `for ( i <- 0 until remain.size) { ... }` evaluates to `(0 until remain.size).foreach({ ... })`, which evaluates to `Unit` (no matter what is done in the block)

  - See documentation: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops
- It doesn't really matter what happened in the for-loop because `cum` is returned anyways, from the base invocation

If you do not want permutations, but by "combinations" you mean "subsets" (i.e. get the power set of the original set):

```scala
def findAllCombinations(remain:Seq[Int]) : List[Seq[Int]]=  {
  remain match {
    case head :: tail =>
      val tailCombinations = findAllCombinations(tail)
      tailCombinations.flatMap((combo: Seq[Int]) => Seq(head +: combo, combo))
    case _ => List(Seq())
  }
}
val x = findAllCombinations(Seq(1,2,3))
println(x)
println(x.length)
```

Output:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(2, 3), List(1, 3), List(3), List(1, 2), List(2), List(1), List())
8
```